# How to simplify elseif chains in Roblox Studio LUAU language

Tags: optimization, lua, game-development, roblox

I have a script that displays a group icon above your characters head, for each group defined there's a separate icon, below those icons it displays the rank you have in the first priority group, then your players name is underneath that rank name, however I haven't been able to find a way to simplify the script without defining over eighty+ elseif chains, here's a basic version of what the script looks like:

```
local LogoPos = {
    [1] = {
        [1] = UDim2.new(0.45,0,0,0)
    };
    [2] = {
        [1] = UDim2.new(0.325,0,0,0);
        [2] = UDim2.new(0.525,0,0,0);
    }
}

local Groups = {
    Group1 = 7;
    Group2 = 10;
    Group3 = 11;
}

local Priority = {
    Group1 = 1;
    Group2 = 2;
    Group3 = 3;
}

local Players = game:GetService("Players")

local function SetupRankGui(Player)
    repeat wait() until Player.Character ~= nil
    local pGroups = {Group1 = false; Group2 = false;}
    local RankGui = game:GetService("ServerStorage").RankGUI:Clone()
    RankGui.PlayerName.Text = Player.Name
    Player.Character.Humanoid.DisplayDistanceType = "None"
    local Trues = 0

    if Player:IsInGroup(Groups.Group1) then
        pGroups.Group1 = true
        RankGui.Group1.Visible = true
    end
    if Player:IsInGroup(Groups.Group2) then
        --same as above but for group2
    end
    if Player:IsInGroup(Groups.Group3) then
        --same as for group1 but for group3
    end
    
    for i,v in pairs(pGroups) do
        if v == true then
           Trues = Trues + 1 
        end
    end
    
    if Trues == 0 then
        RankGui.PlayerRank.Text = "Visitor"
        RankGui.Parent = Players[Player.Name].Character.Head
    elseif Trues == 1 then
        if pGroups.Group1 then
            RankGui.Group1.Position = LogoPos[1][1]
            RankGui.PlayerRank.Text = Player:GetRoleInGroup(Group1)
            RankGui.Parent = Players[Player.Name].Character.Head
            return
        elseif pGroups.Group2 then
            --Same as above but for Group2
        end
    elseif Trues == 2 then
        if pGroups.Group1 and pGroups.Group2 then
            RankGui.Group1.Position = LogoPos[2][2]
            RankGui.Group2.Position = LogoPos[2][2]
            RankGui.PlayerRank.Text = Player:GetRoleInGroup(Group1)
            RankGui.Parent = Players[Player.Name].Character.Head
        elseif pGroups.Group2 and pGroups.Group3 then
            --Same as above but setting Group2 and Group3 positions instead
        end
    end
end

repeat wait() until script.Parent:IsA("Model") and script.Parent:IsDescendantOf(workspace)
SetupRankGui(Players[script.Parent.Name])
```

I have about six groups in the script with six specific locations with almost all possible group combinations etc, there's over 700 lines of code for the script which I want to minimise as much as possible, I just can't think of an alternative for elseif chains other than maybe pairs() which I'm not too experienced with, the script eventually turns into just lines of this but with slight differences of each to meet all possible use-cases:

```
elseif Trues == 4 then
    if pGroups.Group1 and pGroups.Group2 and pGroups.Group3 and pGroups.Group4 then
        RankGui.Group1.Position = LogoPos[4][1]
        RankGui.Group2.Position = LogoPos[4][2]
        RankGui.Group3.Position = LogoPos[4][3]
        RankGui.Group4.Position = LogoPos[4][4]
        RankGui.PlayerRank.Text = Player:GetRoleInGroup(Groups.Group1)
        RankGui.Parent = Players[Player.Name].Character.Head
        return
    elseif pGroups.Group1 and pGroups.Group2 and pGroups.Group3 and pGroups.Group5 then
        RankGui.Group1.Position = LogoPos[4][1]
        RankGui.Group2.Position = LogoPos[4][2]
        RankGui.Group3.Position = LogoPos[4][3]
        RankGui.Group5.Position = LogoPos[4][4]
        RankGui.PlayerRank.Text = Player:GetRoleInGroup(Groups.Group1)
        RankGui.Parent = Players[Player.Name].Character.Head
        return
    elseif pGroups.Group1 and pGroups.Group2 and pGroups.Group3 and pGroups.Group6 then
        RankGui.Group1.Position = LogoPos[4][1]
        RankGui.Group2.Position = LogoPos[4][2]
        RankGui.Group3.Position = LogoPos[4][3]
        RankGui.Group6.Position = LogoPos[4][4]
        RankGui.PlayerRank.Text = Player:GetRoleInGroup(Groups.Group1)
        RankGui.Parent = Players[Player.Name].Character.Head
        return
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to get the team first, and then using variables, modify the code, for example:

```lua
local team = Player:GetTeam().Name --or similar, don't actually know how to use that
pGroups:FindFirstChild(team) = true
RankGui:FindFirstChild(team).Visible = true
```

And apply that to everything applicable.
Also try to use lists and foreaches.
In recap: Get value, write only once, run code but modify it with value.
I hope you get what im trying to say.